# Getting NaN values athough after assigning values to the column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Edit**

*i found and corrected the reason of getting NaN values but still skipping problem of some column is not solved :(.*

I'm trying to figure out how many times at least three consecutive green and red candels formed at zero hour UTC in the previous days. If there are more than three consecutive candles, my code will only generate a column name of "Green_X" or "Red_X," where X denotes the length of the candles. But in the output, I do see the column names, but the values are NaN. What am I doing wrong here? Also, some columns appear to be skipped, such as Green_8, Green_10, and Green_11, while others, such as Green_12, appear to be generated. Logically without 8, 10, and 11, 12 can't be generated.

**Main Logic for updating the DATAFRAME**

```
# iterate through the rows in the 0 hour group
for index, row in df_0.iterrows():
  # if the current row has a green candle (close > open)
  if row['close'] > row['open']:
    #Increase Green value
      green_formations += 1
      #Update the new red consecutive candle number if required
      if red_formations >= 3:
        if "Red_"+str(red_formations) in results_df.columns:
          results_df["Red_"+str(red_formations)] += 1;
        else:
          results_df["Red_"+str(red_formations)] = [1]
      red_formations = 0
```

**Full CODE**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Load the dataframe
df = pd.read_csv("/content/DATA/EURJPY Minute.csv",nrows = 50000)

# create a new dataframe to hold the results
results_df = pd.DataFrame()

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

# group the dataframe by hour
df = df.groupby(df['time'].dt.hour).apply(lambda x: x)

# select only the 0 hour group
df_0 = df[df['time'].dt.hour == 0]


# initialize counters for green and red formations
green_formations = 0
red_formations = 0


# iterate through the rows in the 0 hour group
for index, row in df_0.iterrows():
  # if the current row has a green candle (close > open)
  if row['close'] > row['open']:
      green_formations += 1
      if red_formations >= 3:
        if "Red_"+str(red_formations) in results_df.columns:
          results_df["Red_"+str(red_formations)] += 1;
        else:
          results_df["Red_"+str(red_formations)] = [1]
      red_formations = 0
  # if the current row has a red candle (close < open)
  elif row['close'] < row['open']:
      red_formations += 1
      if green_formations >= 3:
        if "Green_"+str(green_formations) in results_df.columns:
          results_df["Green_"+str(green_formations)] +=1;
        else:
          results_df["Green_"+str(green_formations)] = [1]
      green_formations = 0
  else: # ie equaL CASE
    if green_formations >= 3:
      if "Green_"+str(green_formations) in results_df.columns:
        results_df["Green_"+str(green_formations)] +=1;
      else:
        results_df["Green_"+str(green_formations)] = [1]
    elif red_formations >= 3:
        if "Red_"+str(red_formations) in results_df.columns:
          results_df["Red_"+str(red_formations)] +=1;
        else:
          results_df["Red_"+str(red_formations)] = [1]
    green_formations=0
    red_formations=0

# display the results
print(results_df)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Green_4, Red_3, Red_4, Red_5, Green_5, Green_3, Red_8, Green_7, Red_6, Green_6, Green_9, Green_12, Red_7, Red_9]
Index: []
```

***CSV file Sample***

```
time    open    high    low close   volume
0   2011-02-08 09:22:00 111.598 111.627 111.580 111.614 56
1   2011-02-08 09:23:00 111.623 111.625 111.600 111.619 36
2   2011-02-08 09:24:00 111.613 111.636 111.603 111.611 42
3   2011-02-08 09:25:00 111.610 111.619 111.593 111.609 30
4   2011-02-08 09:26:00 111.611 111.644 111.602 111.628 46
```

Comment: That is a lot code @Sewatech...Debug yourself by adding check points in your code. You will understand where logic is wrong & then post that part..

Comment: @Sewatech are you sure you need a results_df and not just a dict, with keys being the string you construct?
It looks as you'll have a single row results_df with multiple columns. what is the added value of it?

Comment: @Meny yes I just need single row for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

Your code has an indentation problem, so I hope I got everything right.
I'm no Dataframes expert, but you're basically using it as a dict

You have no rows in `results_df` yet you try to increase a counter in given columns. but there's no row to manipulate, so I believe it's being ignored.

I'm taken a different approach, as the number of your columns is final, you can pre-populate the results dataframe with the columns an a zeroes row

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Load the dataframe
df = pd.read_csv("/content/DATA/EURJPY Minute.csv",nrows = 50000)

# create a new dataframe to hold the results
result_structure = {"Red_0": [0], "Red_1": [0], "Red_2": [0], "Red_3": [0], "Green_0": [0], "Green_1": [0], "Green_2": [0], "Green_3": [0]}
results_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=result_structure)

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

# group the dataframe by hour
df = df.groupby(df['time'].dt.hour).apply(lambda x: x)

# select only the 0 hour group
df_0 = df[df['time'].dt.hour == 0]
# initialize counters for green and red formations
green_formations = 0
red_formations = 0

for index, row in df_0.iterrows():
    # if the current row has a green candle (close > open)
    if row['close'] > row['open']:
        green_formations += 1
        if red_formations >= 3:
            if "Red_"+str(red_formations) in results_df.columns:
                results_df["Red_"+str(red_formations)] += 1;
            else:
                results_df["Red_"+str(red_formations)] = red_formations
            red_formations = 0
    # if the current row has a red candle (close < open)
    elif row['close'] < row['open']:
        red_formations += 1
        if green_formations >= 3:
            if "Green_"+str(green_formations) in results_df.columns:
                results_df["Green_"+str(green_formations)] +=1;
            else:
                results_df["Green_"+str(green_formations)] = green_formations
            green_formations = 0
    else: # ie equaL CASE
        if green_formations >= 3:
            if "Green_"+str(green_formations) in results_df.columns:
                results_df["Green_"+str(green_formations)] +=1;
            else:
                results_df["Green_"+str(green_formations)] = green_formations
        elif red_formations >= 3:
            if "Red_"+str(red_formations) in results_df.columns:
                results_df["Red_"+str(red_formations)] +=1;
            else:
                results_df["Red_"+str(red_formations)] = red_formations
        green_formations=0
        red_formations=0

# display the results
print(results_df)
```

And this is what I got from the few samples you provided (I had to tweak it, and change the hour from 09 to 00)

```
   Red_0  Red_1  Red_2  Red_3  Green_0  Green_1  Green_2  Green_3
0      0      0      0      2        0        0        0        1
```

Personally speaking,
I still believe the proper usage here is a dictionary, as it's much more suitable than a results df.

You can even utilize the defaultdict(int) to save you the need to set either 0 or to increment. will make your code much more elegant.
Afterwards you can turn it into a dataframe if you still need to.

Comment: Oh, I just realized what a silly mistake I made. I should have assigned the value in datatables with [1] instead of 1 directly.